# Making boxes at the head of a formal proposal.

Tags: tables

I'm working on making a proposal. The proposal should have boxes as follows from the MS-Word template, but I'd like to use LaTeX for better output quality. I can think of screen capturing from MS-Word and use \includegraphics, but I believe I have a better choice.

How can I make a sequence of text and boxes using LaTeX?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possibility, fine tune the vertical spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[scale]{tgheros}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}\sffamily
\begin{center}
\large\bfseries NSF EPSCoR PROJECT DESCRIPTION
\end{center}
\medskip
{\bfseries\hspace{\fboxrule}\hspace{\fboxsep}Title}\\
\framebox[\textwidth][l]{Hello World}\\
{\bfseries\hspace{\fboxrule}\hspace{\fboxsep}Lead Investigator}\\
\framebox[\textwidth][l]{Investigator}\\
{\bfseries\hspace{\fboxrule}\hspace{\fboxsep}Institution}\\
\framebox[\textwidth][l]{Institution XYZ}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]